# How to apply remaining width to a div in the middle of 2 other divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill remaning area of screen with the second div, div 1 and 2 got fixed width. How could i achive this effect?

HTML

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Problem can be fixed by using this CSS code, when second div is set to auto it will fill remaning area left to be filled.

```
#div1 {
float:left;
width:400px;
height:200px;
background-color: gray;
}
#div2 {
float:right;
width:400px;
height:200px;
background-color: green; 
}
#div3 {
margin-left: 400px;
margin-right: 400px;
width:auto;
height:200px;
background-color: silver;
}
```

**Edit**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classically, this would look like this:

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: gray;
}
#div2 {
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    width:auto;
    height:200px;
    background-color: silver;
}
#div3 {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/5AJkn/

P.S: expand your screen > 800px to prevent the layout from breaking. Could also be solved by adding a min-width to a new parent element.

Comment: i don't know why this answer has so many up votes, but this answer actually modifies op's HTML, which is not necessary. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5AJkn/1/ - How It works on original markup)

Comment: @user3616064 how is this exactly what you were looking for..? this is not the html structure you shared in the question..!

Comment: you are right @TJ I did this to show, what needs to be changed. But of course the change in the html is not really necessary. But your demo is broken. If anything, it should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/5AJkn/2/ to keep the dom like it is.

Comment: you got me, its not exacly what i was looking for however its easier to change one line of html then express it with much more css code. to achive same effect while keeping html structure.

Comment: @user3616064 yes tj is right, i posted the solution for this within my comment above. Good look.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `position: relative` for their parent (if it is not positioned already) and
apply the following to div2:

```
#div2{
    position:absolute;
    left:400px; /* width of div1 */
    right:400px; /* width of div3 */
    height:200px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9GfaZ/1/)

You can use css3 `calc()` function if older browser support is not an issue.

```
#div2{
    display:inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 800px); /*100% - width of div1 and div3 */
    height:200px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9GfaZ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If your browser support calc, you coudl try:

```
#div2 { float:left; width:calc(100% - 800px); height:200px; }
```

Add the margins too, if any.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .box{display: table;width: 100%;}
    #div1{width:400px; height:200px;background: #000;display: table-cell}
    #div2{width:auto; height:200px;background: #e6e6e6;display: table-cell}
    #div3{width:400px; height:200px;background: #000;display: table-cell}
</style>

<div class="box">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2">ds</div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the same questions that :

- [Positioning two divs, one with fixed width(left div) and other in percentage(right div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703996/positioning-two-divs-one-with-fixed-widthleft-div-and-other-in-percentagerig/20140843#20140843)
- [Two divs side by side, one with google map and second with fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092803/two-divs-side-by-side-one-with-google-map-and-second-with-fixed-width/20099168#20099168)

[This Codepen fix your problem](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/kEJrL)